# ConfigureAwait(false) on the single line

Tags: c#, async-await

Is it make any sense to write `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the single code line like:

```
private async Task test()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>{}).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

If [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) says that `ConfigureAwait(false)` affects only on method "tail".

```
async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    // Code here runs in the original context.
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // Code here runs in the original context.
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    // Code here runs without the original
    // context (in this case, on the thread pool).
}
```

Comment: Did you read the next line "*By using ConfigureAwait, you enable a small amount of parallelism: Some asynchronous code can run in parallel with the GUI thread instead of constantly badgering it with bits of work to do*" - adding to that, it gives you are small amount of efficiency by not needing to create a continuation on the calling thread.   in short the code is fine, as long as you understand what it does, and what problems it can cause

Comment: Peter the `test` method awaits a `Task.Run(() => { })`. The `MyMethodAsync` method awaits two `Task.Delay(1000)`. Is this difference in the type of the awaitable, and the number of the awaitables, significant for the question that you are asking? I am asking because I am trying to understand what exactly you are asking.

Comment: What if anything this does depends on multiple factors. Does this code have a UI thread or other synchronisation context? You should read this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait(false)` has affect only on non completed awaitables (`Task`-like types) and only when under a `SynchronizationContext`.

The first simple example, if `ConfigureAwait(false)` is ommited:

```cs
private async Task test()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>{});
}
```

If the `test` method is running under a `SynchronizationContext`, the continuation after the `await` will be posted to that `SynchronizationContext`.

Refer to the [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) for a more detailed explanation.